# Apple Wireless CarPlay

Tags: range-rover

I have a vehicle that supports Apple CarPlay, but I've only managed to get it working when using a USB cable. Is there a way to get it working wirelessly over bluetooth?

Specifically the vehicle is a Range Rover Evoque (mk 2) if that makes a difference.

Comment: I was looking at a brand new Ford, and from the owner’s manual Apple CarPlay there only works via USB cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your iPhone, go to settings. Pick “general”. Once in general settings choose CarPlay. A bubble should pop up displaying USB and WIRELESS. Choose wireless. This should help with your issue. It has always worked for mine! Good luck hope this helps

Comment: That sounds like it might be specific to certain iPhones as I don't see a "bubble" on my iPhone Xs Max, but I might test this with another iPhone.

Comment: If you don’t mind me asking, which iPhone you have and software it’s running. I believe that setting came about ios13 maybe ios14?

Comment: So I did some checking, CarPlay setting is available on any iPhone5 or newer And running iOS software 7.1 or newer. I hope this will help you

Comment: @MatthewLayton you might want to edit your question to include the year of your vehicle for future searchers, however many older vehicles only support carplay over USB. The blue tooth is only for cellular interaction.

Comment: On one car AirPlay works only via USB (Opel Corsa), on another (Toyota Yaris) it works also on wireless (but it needs both usb and wifi).